# logging frameworks and logback.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, logback

While creating an example using Java and the com.alvazan.orm.api library, the use of "System.out.println" is prohibited.

One of the first and most simple Java exercises learned is "Hello World", also using the 
"System.out.println" (...also known as logging, or returned requested data found in the console?)
When using Eclipse, logging is turned off by modifying the logback.xml file (ctrl-shift-R and typing in logback.xml)

From there;
`<logger name="com.alvazan.orm" level="WARN"/>`
is the line to add to the logback.xml file so that only startup logs appear.

In addition, two more logs such as....
`2012-09-14 22:05:08,067 com.alvazan.test.FactorySingleton createFactory` 
`INFO: CREATING FACTORY FOR TESTS`
`2012-09-14 22:05:08,809 com.impetus.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer processFile` 
`INFO: adding folder to scan=file:/C:/AAROOT/workareas/area1/playorm/eclipsegen/`
are used.

- Just clarifying that all information is typed into the logback.xml file?
- Is there a diffrent file to use(other than logback.xml)?
- Or is the end-user to use, for instance, "com.alvazan.test.FactorySingleton createFactory"; and "com.impetus.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer processFile"?
- Finalizing this question, is the file path for the preceeding necessary?

Thanks for your time,
Ryan

---

In response to Brett, and additional information/questions,

How is your root logger configured? You are only setting WARN for com.alvazan.orm, so if your root logger is INFO, then com.alvazan.test INFO's will be logged.

Hey Brett, thanks for the reply...

As for the root logger configuration, I believe the value is set at "INFO".
 
[image: logback.xml] 
That being said, I would want to set "INFO" to "WARN", to prevent the use of 
"System.out.println" 
Also in the previous question, I mentioned:

> 2012-09-14 22:05:08,067 com.alvazan.test.FactorySingleton createFactory
>   INFO: CREATING FACTORY FOR TESTS
>   2012-09-14 22:05:08,809 com.impetus.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer processFile
>   INFO: adding folder to scan=file:/C:/AAROOT/workareas/area1/playorm/eclipsegen/

com.alvazan.test.FactorySingleton
and
com.impetus.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer (diffrent package within same library)

Different locations found within the same library...
[image: Library]

Do i need to do the logback process for the other files, or *package, or doing it one time within the same library, should suffice for all? Or do I adjust additional values?

Comment: You may find the configuration section of the logback manual relevant reading: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your first statement....

> "While creating an example using Java and the com.alvazan.orm.api
>   library, the use of "System.out.println" is prohibited."

In general, no one uses in System.out.println.  Hibernate does not, JBoss does not, tomcat does not.  They all use a logging framework so you can configure each and every log in production and each company using tomcat or jboss or hibernate can configure it differently.  If these programs use System.out.println, customers would have no control and your server would ALWAYS run slow as you NEVER want "all" logging and there is no way to turn System.out.println's off!!!!!  they are always on.  log.info can be turned off and on.

The most complete answer on configuring logback can be found in their documentation

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

> Just clarifying that all information is typed into the logback.xml
>   file?

I am not sure what you mean by this question.  logback.xml is the configuration for a logging library called logback which you can find at the link above.

```
Is there a diffrent file to use(other than logback.xml)?
```

logback has other options like a groovy file to configure it, but playOrm is using only logback.xml though any client can decide what configuration file they use since playOrm discards the logback.xml file that is checked in when delivering to other projects.

```
Or is the end-user to use, for instance, "com.alvazan.test.FactorySingleton createFactory"; 
and "com.impetus.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer processFile"?
```

I am very confused by this question.  The end user should not be using FactorySingleton(neither directly nor indirectly AND that class is not even in the jar because it's in the test package).  The end-user will be using ClasspathDiscoverer only indirectly...in fact, end-user won't even know about these classes.

```
Finalizing this question, is the file path for the preceeding necessary?
```

Are you trying to ask is the file path in logback.xml necessary?  If you want to know more about how logback works, you need to read alot of the documentation.  Basically, you can do stuff like com.alvazan level=WARN to turn any classes in com.alvazan.**** to warn level(This is recursive and applies to children, grandchildren, etc. etc.).  The ROOT logger is always defined as well in logback.xml and is the level for ALL classes in a all packages unless overridden.

yes, the root logger in playorm is set to warn.

At the bottom of the picture you show(your picture is cut off so not in that picture), there is a "source" tab and you may want to click that to view the xml better and it would match up with logback's documentation better as well.  Here is a link to the file I bet you are looking at..

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/486079cfefbd2b4b79e99652b24c146572663dda/input/javasrc/logback.xml

root logger is clearly set to info and could be set to warn if you want.

So, what do you want.  Do you want those two log statements to go away and be turned off?  Do you want ALL log statements to be turned off except WARN?

If you want all to be turned off in ALL software libraries, just change the root logger to "WARN".  If you want to turn just FactorySingleton off you can add this line

```
<logger name="com.alvazan.test.FactorySingleton" level=""WARN"/>
```

If you want all of com.alvazan logging turned off instead of just everything in com.alvazan.orm as you also want com.alvazan.test off as well, BUT you want all other libraries to still be on(BUT always want WARN on which you generally should want), then you could change this

```
<logger name="com.alvazan.orm" level=""WARN"/>
```

to the following instead

```
<logger name="com.alvazan" level=""WARN"/>
```

Your best bet to understand logback though is to read logback documentation.

Comment: I have a requirement to access logback.xml from external folder for project mainly this xml file will be common for two projects which needs to access from outside. Should logback.xml file in project class path? can we load in class path from outside folder?  Please suggest.

Comment: yes, that is just a java thing not a logabck thing....just specify that external folder ont he classpath first so that logback.xml gets loaded before any other logback.xml on the classpath(though hopefully that is the only logback.xml you have on the classpath).  you can read up on classpath and classloading on the web about this.

Comment: Dean. I think I need to spacify full path of logback.xml in class path right?

Comment: Dean. logback.xml is outside of project so can I add it through tomact/weblogic vm argument?

Comment: you can read the logback.xml documentation if there is another way, but you can also tell tomcat to include the directory that has the logback.xml in it's base classpath.

Comment: this question is better asked as a logback question on stackoverflow.  the logback/slf4j was the log4j lead and slf4j can adapt any logger without the issues of commons logging so you can use all 3rd party libraries and have them all log to one infrastructure and controller by one config file.

Answer (score 0):

How is your root logger configured? You are only setting WARN for com.alvazan.orm, so if your root logger is INFO, then com.alvazan.test INFO's will be logged.